# GPU L2 cache hit is 100% and DRAM load transactions sometimes is 0

Tags: caching, cuda, gpu

I am experimenting a simple matrix multiplication CUDA program. I found if the matrix size is small (512*512 or smaller), the L2 cache hit rate is always 100%. The profiled DRAM read transactions is not stable, sometimes the value is even 0. Is this possible? Because there should always be some cold misses in L2 cache and then L2 fetches those data from DRAM. So DRAM read transactions should never be 0 and the L2 hit rate should be less than 100%.

FYI: I tested the program on Quadro K6000 GPU which uses Kepler 40 architecture. The metric values are the same no matter L1 cache is turned on or off. The metrics I used include l2_l1_read_hit_rate and dram_read_transactions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Yes, it's possible.

Note that **all** DRAM activity flows through the L2 cache, which cannot be disabled (atomics are a special case, but presumably not in view here.)  This includes `cudaMemcpy` traffic as well.

Therefore, if I transfer from host to device a "small" data set that fits entirely in L2 cache, and then launch a kernel that reads in this data set, it will likely already be resident in L2, and the read transactions will "hit" in L2 and may not generate any actual DRAM activity.

(For a device with L1 enabled, there are a number of traffic types which *do not* flow through the L1, including `cudaMemcpy` traffic.  Therefore L1 enabled/disabled should generally have no effect on the hypothetical case I've outlined here.  The initial kernel reads would all "miss" in L1 but "hit" in L2).

Comment: Do you mean after cudaMemcpy, the data can be cached from DRAM into L2 automatically even before the kernel launch?

Comment: Yes.  That is correct.  The process of copying the data from the host to GPU DRAM **flows through the L2 cache** and so it gets cached in L2 as it is being copied to DRAM.